# dabeng Org Chart Php Mysql Ajax

Tags: javascript, php, mysql

Hello i have a data like parent and child in loop , how to convert to dabeng format  https://codepen.io/dabeng/post/orgchart ?  i have like this :

```
    $data_cst = array();
    foreach($list as $row){
        $data = array(
            'name' => $row->nama,
            'title' =>  $row->posisi,
            'relationship' => $row->atasan
        );

        array_push($data_cst, $data);
    }
    echo json_encode($data_cst);
```

Comment: Do you have children key s well ? @user3300313

Comment: sure i have id, nama, posisi, atasan :
id as key, 
atasan as key parent

Comment: i want output Like this :
{
  'name': 'Lao Lao',
  'title': 'general manager',
  'relationship': '001',
  'children': [
    { 'name': 'Bo Miao', 'title': 'department manager', 'relationship': '110' },
    { 'name': 'Su Miao', 'title': 'department manager', 'relationship': '111',
      'children': [
        { 'name': 'Tie Hua', 'title': 'senior engineer', 'relationship': '110' },
        { 'name': 'Hei Hei', 'title': 'senior engineer', 'relationship': '110' }
      ]
    },
    { 'name': 'Yu Jie', 'title': 'department manager', 'relationship': '110' }
  ]
};

Answer (score 0):

convert your array like this

```
$data_cst =  array("nama" => "lalit", "posisi" => "mohan","atasan" => 
"chawla","children" => [array("nama" => "lalit", "posisi" => 
"mohan","atasan" => "chawla" )]);

echo json_encode($data_cst);
```

Use this parser to view the result

[parser](http://json.parser.online.fr/)

This will help you

```
$data_cst = array();
foreach($list as $row){
    $data = array(
        'name' => $row->nama,
        'title' =>  $row->posisi,
        'relationship' => $row->atasan,
        'children' => [$row->children]
    );

    array_push($data_cst, $data);
}
echo json_encode($data_cst);
```

Comment: How i get  [$row->children] ?? But this from the record